# How can I set pointer to a string in a binary file?

Tags: c, parsing, binary, ascii, decode

I have a binary file that I need to parse for certain strings and set a pointer to.

The data is in the following format:

```
typedef struct{
 int ID;
 int DataSize;
 void* Data;
}
```

So in byte format,

16 03 48 45 59 17 05 48 45 4C 4C 4F

ID - 16 , DataSize = 3 , String (0x48, 0x45, 0x59) - HEY

ID - 17 , DataSize = 5 , String (0x48, 0x45, 0x4C, 0x4C, 0x4F)- HELLO

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to set a pointer to only point to HEY and none of the data after so that I can print it out. I'm pretty sure I need to use the DataSize some how. I am parsing the binary file byte by byte.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it with a pointer, since a string needs to end with a 0 character.

but you can make a

```
strncpy(buffer, x.Data, x.DataSize); 
buffer[x.DataSize]='\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` actually *can* print unterminated strings. If you don't want to copy your data, you can prepare an individual format string for your data:

```
char format[20];
sprintf(format, "%%%ds\n", x.dataSize);
printf(format, x.data);
```